# ktpass.exe failing with ldap_open failed for default server: 0x3a

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to generate a keytab file [using the instructions online here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2018/01/03/all-you-need-to-know-about-keytab-files/). No matter what I do, whether I run this on a domain controller, a member server, in PowerShell as administrator, in cmd as administrator, I get the same error:

```
ktpass /out app1.keytab /princ http/adtrml0.ml.test@ml.test /mapuser mlservice /crypto AES256-SHA1 /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /pass myP@ssword477 /target adtrml0.ml.test

Using legacy password setting method
FAIL: ldap_open failed for default server: 0x3a.
```

I cannot seem to find any information online about this error.

I even tried creating a fresh domain with a single DC and running this on the new DC right after promoting it, and I still get this error.

Any idea what this is all about and how I can address it?

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the problem was a misconfigured subnet mask!

My subnet mask was too big for the subnet. After changing it to the appropriate size, all the commands that were failing passed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [instructions you referred](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2018/01/03/all-you-need-to-know-about-keytab-files/) it says

`/target is used to indicate which domain controller will be queried (it is optional, but can be useful if you have more than one domain in your forest)`

I guess the argument you supplied for `\target` is web server domain name `adtrml0.ml.test`.

It should be the valid domain controller name of the AD Server. `Example: dc1.company.com`